# Basic math operation in C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning and have glanced over simple math operations in C#. However, a point that may be easy-peasy seems interesting that typically I know about division an integer by an another integer number is zero if first one is smaller than second one. So, I have looked at [operator precedence in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) because maybe I have the wrong information about it. So, what about `Console.WriteLine((1 + 1) / 2 * 3);` Shouldn't it give zero as a result? But it gives `3`. Is there a point that I have wrong knowledge about C#?

<s>**@Edit:** The problem is about my arithmetic. I think it should be 2 / 2 * 3 then 2 / 6 = 0 why division takes place before multiplication?</s>

<s>**@Edit 2:** The question can be closed. It is exactly about my wrong knowledge on precedence of operators. I had thought like a real math procedure in programming until now. I'm in shock. ***Advantages of the reading again and again and not skipping even if you supposed as I know the subject already***</s>

**@Edit 3:** After some time, I realized that there are some sorts of evaluation of math expressions called as like, [PEMDAS, BODMAS, BEDMAS and BIDMAS](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Order_of_operations). That's why I got it wrong at first.

Comment: Why would you expect it to give 0? Where do you believe there's division of one integer by a larger? That expression will have the same result in Java at least.

Comment: Please explain why you think that if you add 1 and 1 (yielding 2), then divide that by 2 (yielding 1) and then multiply that by 3, you shouldn't get 3.

Comment: (1+1) / 2 * 3 would translate into 2 / 2 * 3 and then 1 * 3 and essentially 3. Why would it ever end up in 0? :|

Comment: You're problem is not with C# but arithmetic

Comment: I have edited the question Mr @JonSkeet.

Comment: 2 / 2 * 3 is still 3, because `/` has the same precedence as `*`, so they're evaluated left to right - it's (2 / 2) * 3, not 2 / (2 * 3). And again, I'd expect the same to be true in any of the other languages you've mentioned.

Comment: I'm in shock how I had failed to notice until now. Thanks Mr @JonSkeet

Comment: As an aside, I would avoid this and always explicitly bracket - `((1 + 1) / 2) * 3`. Obviously you don't have to, it is a personal preference - but it makes it absolutely clear how you inteded the equation to work, as well as helping avoid any issues with anyone reading it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the order of operations. [image: order of operations]
From this image, you can derive that you first need to add the two ones between parentheses. This will then be divided by 2. Finally, you multiply by three.

So (**1+1**)/2*3

Then **2/2** *3

Finally **1*3**

As you can see multiply and divide gets executed from left to right. Multiplication isn't executed before the division.

Comment: PEMDAS or not, if there's ambiguity, then it's up to the writer of the code to make the intent clear and get rid of ambiguity. This is the best approach, and the scientific approach as well. It will not lead to any confusion, certainly if people are used to other methods. Never leave it up to the one who's reading the code to see what the intent should be... (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76647212/1155847).

Answer (score 4):

the answer is 3.. 1+1 = 2 /2 = 1 * 3 = 3..... order of operations tells us this

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate confusion, you can use parentheses even when they aren't necessary.  This helps the next person who reads your code.

Ex: a = ((1 + 1) / 2) * 3.  If you desired the answer to be 0, then a = (1 + 1) / (2 * 3).  This makes the code easier to read and will help eliminate simple math errors that can be very difficult to find in complex operations.

Comment: This above is indeed the right answer, always be explicit about your order of operations as otherwise nobody knows the context! PEMDAS or not, it doesn't matter, it's the responsibility of the writer to leave ambiguity out of the formula/calculation.

Answer (score 1):

**Always be explicit about your intent**. So, **make sure there's no ambiguity** and use parentheses to show your intent on the order of operations. Otherwise nobody knows the context! PEMDAS (or other contexts/standards) or not, it doesn't matter, it's the responsibility of the writer to leave ambiguity out of the formula/calculation and make the intent very clear for anyone reading it.

**For example**: `a/b*(c+d)` could be read in two ways, we leave ambiguity in the formula. So, you'd be better off to add parentheses to either say:

- `a/(b*(c+d))`
- `(a/b) * (c+d)`

This gives context (aka *clear intent*) to anyone else reading your code, or the formula.

**Some videos to watch as reference:**

- MinutePhysics on the "Order of Operations": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9h1oqv21Vs
- "PEMDAS is wrong": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLCDca6dYpA
- "The problem with PEMDAS: Why Calculators Disagree": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4x-BcYCiKCk